# Replacing strings in Pandas DataFrame column with array of entries based on dict

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dictionary

I have a DataFrame such as:

```
     tag1   other
0    a,c      foo
1    b,c      foo
2    d        foo
3    a,a      foo
```

Of which the entries are strings delimited by commas.

And a dict of definitions for each tag such as:

```
dict = {'a' : 'Apple',
'b' : 'Banana',
'c' : 'Carrot'}
```

I would like to replace the definitions of `a`, `b`, and `c` but delete rows in which there is something not within that dict (i.e. `d`). Furthermore, I'd like to ensure there are no duplicates, such as row index 3 in the example dataset.

What I have so far:

```
df.tags = df.tags.str.split(',')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    names = []
    for tag in row.tag1:
            if tag == dict[tag]:
                names.append(dict[tag])
            else:
                 df.drop(df.index[index])
```

From there I would replace the original column with the values in `names`. To replace duplicates, I am thinking of iterating over the array and checking if the next value matches the next, and if so, deleting it. However, this is not working and I am a bit stumped. The desired output would look like (with strings in unicode):

```
     tag1                     other
0    ['Apple', 'Carrot']      foo
1    ['Banadn', 'Carrot']     foo
3    ['Apple']                foo
```

Comment: what does the desired output look like?

Comment: I have edited that in, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For my entry into the longest one liner competition

```
m = {
    'a' : 'Apple',
    'b' : 'Banana',
    'c' : 'Carrot'
}

df.tag1.str.split(',', expand=True) \ 
  .stack().map(m).groupby(level=0) \
  .filter(lambda x: x.notnull().all()) \
  .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().str.cat(sep=',')) \
  .to_frame('tag1').join(df.other)

            tag1 other
0   Apple,Carrot   foo
1  Banana,Carrot   foo
3          Apple   foo
```

---

But seriously, probably a better solution

```
a = np.core.defchararray.split(df.tag1.values.astype(str), ',')
lens = [len(s) for s in a]
b = np.concatenate(a)
c = [m.get(k, np.nan) for k in b]
i = df.index.values.repeat(lens)
s = pd.Series(c, i)

def proc(x):
    if x.notnull().all():
        return x.drop_duplicates().str.cat(sep=',')

s.groupby(level=0).apply(proc).dropna().to_frame('tag1').join(df.other)

            tag1 other
0   Apple,Carrot   foo
1  Banana,Carrot   foo
3          Apple   foo
```

Comment: Now, that is some high kicking fruit-fu!

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy if high score wins... then sure :-)

Comment: I'm printing this out and putting this above my work station to cherish this. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that I am only getting one definition per entry in `tags1` with this code even if it contains many tags.

Comment: @Kam are your definitions as you represented them?  Or do they include integers?

Comment: It appears that one of the contents in my data column has an integer - this could be throwing it off perhaps.

Comment: Yes.  try redefining your mapping `m = pd.Series(m).astype(str)`